# Unity camera UI dosen't see the UI

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, game-development

I created a camera, which I want to render only my UI. When I play I don't see the UI in gameplay, but if I change a value in clipping planes or disable the camera and activate it the UI appears, however when I turn off the play the UI disappears again. All children in the canvas have the UI layer

[image: Camera settings]
[image: Canvas settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not at my pc at the moment so I won't be able to test this. But some pointers I'm using for `UI Rendering`.

My first reaction was towards your `near plane` being placed 90 units away from the camera. Usually I prefer to go within 0-1 since I most likely want to render things above 1.

Secondly I usually recommend to go with `Screen space -Overlay` if you only have one UI camera.

Hope this information helps you :)